# Login with Microsoftaccount Azure mobile services c# backend

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I have an azure mobile service with a c# backend. I'm trying to login with a microsoftaccount inside of my xamarin application. Here i'm calling the login method. I do get a pop up to fill in my information but then it wants to open a second pop up and then i get the exception that the request could not be completed:

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed.

`private async Task Authenticate(UIViewController view)
{
   try
   {
       user = await client.LoginAsync(view,MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //something went wrong
    }`

When i used a javascript backend this code worked perfectly but now it somehow does not work anymore. Do i need to add something in the c# backend??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration of the authentication is slightly different. First, the redirect URI should be of the following form:

https://.azure-mobile.net/signin-microsoft

Also, (assuming you are configuring the service through the [My Applications](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=262039&clcid=0x409) page in the Live Connect Developer Center) the settings that I have are as follows:

- Mobile or desktop client app: yes
- Restrict JWT issuing: yes
- Enhanced redirection security: yes

Henrik

Comment: The current login url i have is .azure-mobile.net/login/microsoftaccount. I have the settings the same as you do in the Live Connect Developer Center. Do i need to specify a redirect for after the login in the Live Connect Developer Center?

Comment: Yes, you have to set the redirect URI to the shape above.